# Which to use did or do?

Tags: verbs, past-tense

How should I say when I am telling someone about things I did yesterday?

1) Then, I **do** my homework.

2) Then, I **did** my homework.

Of course that when we are talking about past we should use a past tense word but for this I'm a little bit confused.  For this I will normally use a sentence like `I did my homework yesterday.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence "Then, I do my homework."  Since it is in present tense, it suggests that this is a routine.  On the other hand, "Then, I did my homework." suggests that you did something a while ago.  Hence, if you wanted to tell someone about what you did yesterday, you should use "did".

Comment: Though it's a little bit confusing but refer to your answer, it should be the number 2, right?